# React navigation EventListener not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having a problem with react navigation event listeners not firing, specificly "gestureEnd" is not running the function when the gestureEnds on iphone (swipping left to right to go to a page back)

[image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5a01.png)

i know there is too many console logs but am trying to see where it stops and if its running or not but it runs all the console logs beside the ones inside the listener

Comment: ik allot of things are wrong in the code but i was just trying everything to see if the function inside is being called but i tried everything ik and didnt work

Comment: Your mind is when you swipe to back, app will redirect to SchemeOfWorkScreen?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Can anyone help me to get this same output?